How to create standalone scale that is aware of Observable plot's width, margins, etc
How can I create standalone scale that is aware of Observable plot's width, margins, etc?

I need to create a standalone scale in order to use its scale.apply() method.
However, the resulting scale's apply() function returns values in the range [0,1], not in terms of the plot's dimensions (width, margin, etc).
Compare to plot.scale, which returns values in terms of the plot's dimensions.
I cannot use plot.scale because the scale.apply() function is needed to define the marks that are part of the options when creating the plot. (Sort of a chicken-and-egg problem.)
I tried adding plot dimension options when creating a scale, but these are ignored.
Ideally, the scale could be accessed from the callback where it is used, but this does not seem possible.
Currently, my work-around is to create the plot twice: first to create plot.scale, then again to define the plot that uses plot.scale
Interestingly, if the (Svelte) component is used multiple times, only the first component needs the work-around above. So a "throw-away" component could be hidden.
Another work-around may be to first generate a simple plot for the scale, then use that for the "real" plot.


I have created a simple sample demonstrating the problem below:


const data = [{
    text: 'Weekend',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-16'), end: new Date('2024-06-17'),
  },{
    text: 'Weekdays',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-17'), end: new Date('2024-06-22'),
  }, {
    text: 'Weekend',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-22'), end: new Date('2024-06-23'),
  }]
  
  // Construct scale:
  const scale = Plot.scale({x: {domain: [new Date('2024-06-16'), new Date('2024-06-23')]}})
  
  // Simple plot:
  const plot = Plot.plot({
    height: 150,
    width: 800,
    marginRight: 12,
    marginLeft: 12,
    marks: [
      Plot.rectY(data, {
        x1: (d) => d.utc,
        x2: (d) => d.end,
        y: 1,
        fill: (d) => d.text == 'Weekend' ? 'lightgray': 'beige'
      }),
      Plot.text(data, {
        x: (d) => (Number(d.utc) + Number(d.end))/2,
        text: 'text'
      }),
    ],
  });
  
  function compareScales(value) {
    console.log({
      value,
      '     scale': scale.apply(value),
      'plot.scale': plot.scale('x').apply(value)
    })
  }
  
  compareScales(new Date('2024-06-16')) 
  compareScales(new Date('2024-06-17')) 
  compareScales(new Date('2024-06-23')) 
  

  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');
  div.append(plot);
#myplot {
  height: 200px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

<div id="myplot"></div>




When you create your "standalone" scale just give it the same range as your plot.
const width = 800,
      marginLeft = 12,
      marginRight = 12;

// construct scale
const scale = Plot.scale({
  x: { 
    domain: [ new Date('2024-06-16'), new Date('2024-06-23') ],
    range: [ marginLeft, width - marginRight ] //<-- range matching plot
  },
});

Running example:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #myplot {
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

  <div id="myplot"></div>

  <script>
    const data = [{
        text: 'Weekend',
        utc: new Date('2024-06-16'),
        end: new Date('2024-06-17'),
      },
      {
        text: 'Weekdays',
        utc: new Date('2024-06-17'),
        end: new Date('2024-06-22'),
      },
      {
        text: 'Weekend',
        utc: new Date('2024-06-22'),
        end: new Date('2024-06-23'),
      },
    ];

    const width = 800,
      marginLeft = 12,
      marginRight = 12;

    // Construct scale:
    const scale = Plot.scale({
      x: {
        domain: [new Date('2024-06-16'), new Date('2024-06-23')],
        range: [marginLeft, width - marginRight]
      },
    });

    // Simple plot:
    const plot = Plot.plot({
      height: 150,
      width: width,
      marginRight: marginRight,
      marginLeft: marginLeft,
      marks: [
        Plot.rectY(data, {
          x1: (d) => d.utc,
          x2: (d) => d.end,
          y: 1,
          fill: (d) => (d.text == 'Weekend' ? 'lightgray' : 'beige'),
        }),
        Plot.text(data, {
          x: (d) => (Number(d.utc) + Number(d.end)) / 2,
          text: 'text',
        }),
      ],
    });

    function compareScales(value) {
      console.log({
        value,
        '     scale': scale.apply(value),
        'plot.scale': plot.scale('x').apply(value)
      })
    }

    compareScales(new Date('2024-06-16'))
    compareScales(new Date('2024-06-17'))
    compareScales(new Date('2024-06-23'))

    const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');
    div.append(plot);
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Ah! I thought range was related to the values (y-axis) in the mathematical function sense. It makes sense, now~
